An error occurred during execution of the database script ASP.Net Core Web Application
I created the database of my Asp.net core web api project with Postgresql. I want to create the database with Azure SQL Database while publishing to the Azure platform using the migration method. However, I get the following error during the publish process. Can you help me ?
Error Screenshot
My Migrations:
public partial class startpoint : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Adverts",
            columns: table => new
            {
                AdvertId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
                AdvertName = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                AdvertKilo = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),
                AdvertDescription = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                AdvertDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: true),
                RestaurantId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Adverts", x => x.AdvertId);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Csos",
            columns: table => new
            {
                CsoId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                Username = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                Address = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                Email = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                Password = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                Number = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                RoleId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),
                PasswordSalt = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Csos", x => x.CsoId);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Persons",
            columns: table => new
            {
                PersonId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
                PersonName = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                PersonSurname = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                PersonEmail = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                PersonPassword = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                PersonNickName = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                PersonPhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                RoleId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),
                PasswordSalt = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Persons", x => x.PersonId);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Restaurants",
            columns: table => new
            {
                restaurantId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
                restaurantName = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                restaurantAdress = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                restaurantNickname = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                restaurantMail = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                restaurantPassword = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                restaurantNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                RoleId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),
                PasswordSalt = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Restaurants", x => x.restaurantId);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Roles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                RoleId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
                RoleName = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Roles", x => x.RoleId);
            });
    }

namespace Repositories.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
    partial class ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "7.0.17")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 63);

            NpgsqlModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityByDefaultColumns(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity("Entities.Advert", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("AdvertId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("integer");

                    NpgsqlPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityByDefaultColumn(b.Property<int>("AdvertId"));

                    b.Property<DateTime?>("AdvertDate")
                        .HasColumnType("timestamp with time zone");

                    b.Property<string>("AdvertDescription")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<int>("AdvertKilo")
                        .HasColumnType("integer");

                    b.Property<string>("AdvertName")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<int>("RestaurantId")
                        .HasColumnType("integer");

                    b.HasKey("AdvertId");

                    b.ToTable("Adverts");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Entities.Cso", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("CsoId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("integer");

                    NpgsqlPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityByDefaultColumn(b.Property<int>("CsoId"));

                    b.Property<string>("Address")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("Email")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("Number")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("Password")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("PasswordSalt")
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<int>("RoleId")
                        .HasColumnType("integer");

                    b.Property<string>("Username")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.HasKey("CsoId");

                    b.ToTable("Csos");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Entities.Person", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("PersonId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("integer");

                    NpgsqlPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityByDefaultColumn(b.Property<int>("PersonId"));

                    b.Property<string>("PasswordSalt")
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("PersonEmail")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("PersonName")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("PersonNickName")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("PersonPassword")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("PersonPhoneNumber")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("PersonSurname")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<int>("RoleId")
                        .HasColumnType("integer");

                    b.HasKey("PersonId");

                    b.ToTable("Persons");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Entities.Restaurant", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("restaurantId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("integer");

                    NpgsqlPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityByDefaultColumn(b.Property<int>("restaurantId"));

                    b.Property<string>("PasswordSalt")
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<int>("RoleId")
                        .HasColumnType("integer");

                    b.Property<string>("restaurantAdress")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("restaurantMail")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("restaurantName")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("restaurantNickname")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("restaurantNumber")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<string>("restaurantPassword")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.HasKey("restaurantId");

                    b.ToTable("Restaurants");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Entities.Role", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("RoleId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("integer");

                    NpgsqlPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityByDefaultColumn(b.Property<int>("RoleId"));

                    b.Property<string>("RoleName")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.HasKey("RoleId");

                    b.ToTable("Roles");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}


Asp.net core web application publish from Azure

The migrated code uses the syntax of Npgsql and does not work with Azure SQL Database. It is recommended to use Azure PostgreSQL server, or modify the syntax to support MSSQL.
